# cannot recognize accented characters using TextRecognize

Tags: ocr

Im unable to force TextRecognize understanding Czech characters like "ě, š, č,..." . Adding " .. ; Language -> "Czech" " gives me exactly the same bad result as with "English" or "German". My setup - Mathematica v. 11.2.0.0 plus ThesseractTools added using the "PacletInstall" command. Can somebody test this too? Or please advice to where this has been discussed.
Note: I originally posted this as "comment" to an existing question "Recognizing characters with accent marks" but was told that i shall create separate question, dont understand why but doing.

Comment: seems like it started to work much better, the same commands applied on the same picture file do now produce different results then before. The "ě, š, č,..." characters are being recognized now. And the results seems to change/improve in time. Did somebody started to train the machine now?